# How to know which grid points are closest together in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on  a Qt project. When a user enters points on a mouse click. Is it possible to know which points are closest together? I want to perform calculations on each group of points. Is there built in functions that I can use ?

Comment: Store the QPoint's which are clicked, then run the algorithm of your choice.  You could use the Pythagorean theorem at each click, and store the pair if it's smaller than the previous smallest.

Comment: @shahdewai There are probably any number of distance algorithms, but it'd be wasteful to run one of them on all your grid points. You just by knowing your grid and the click point you should be able to narrow the possibilities to 4 and run the distance algorithm on those 4 points.

Comment: Looks like the nearest neighbour algorithm.